# Drop Down List In A Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have a `GridView`, inside the `GridView` I have a template field and inside that, a drop down list.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Hello" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to databind the `GridView` but how do I make the drop down list change its value to according to the information I gave it while databinding?

Im used to using DataField in bound fields

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Hello" DataField="HelloDB" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is tap into the `OnRowDataBind` event of the `GridView`.  Within that, you can use `FindControl()` to get the drop down, cast it as a `DropDown`, then set the value.

This event is called when each row is databound, so each dropdown would be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides a [walk-through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294(VS.80).aspx) on this.

and quick Bing search comes up with [many other articles](http://www.bing.com/search?q=drop-down+list+in+gridview&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC) and how-to's.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
protected void MethodName(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
     DropDownList Hello = e.Row.FindControl("Hello") as DropDownList;
     //here you can bind the dropdown list.

    }
}
```